# How to persist two object but only update one if it already exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I essentially have a booking system with Booking, Employee and Customer.

I would like to persist a Booking entity. A booking entity has an employee (that will offer the service), and a customer (for which the booking occurs).

I would like to be able to persist a booking object in which the employee and/or the customer will no be created if it already exists. How can I achieve that with JPA and hibernate.

I would also like to keep the current schema that I have (Booking table, Employee table, Customer table and the relationship tables between Booking_customer, Booking_employee ...)

Here is the booking entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Booking
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "booking_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "service")
    private String service;

    @NotNull(message = "status is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BookingStatus status;

    @Column(name = "scheduled_at", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime scheduledAt;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "booking_customer", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")})
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "booking_employee", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")})
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "booking_address", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")})
    private Address address;
}
```

Here is the customer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "firstName is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "lastName is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank(message = "email is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "email_address")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "phoneNumber is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Booking> bookings;
 }
```

Here is the employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "firstName is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "lastName is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email_address")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "phoneNumber is mandatory")
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Booking> bookings;

}
```

I remove getters and setter for clarity.

I would like to be able to persist a booking with a customer and employee through postman like that

```
{
    "title": "Haircut & Beards with Aymen",
    "description": "I would like to clean shave my head",
    "service": "COUPE-12 Haircut",
    "status": "PENDING",
    "scheduledAt": "2021-08-10T15:50:05.609",
    "customer": {
        "firstName": "Raz",
        "lastName": "ari",
        "email": "bena97@gpil.com",
        "phoneNumber": "5149455541"
    },
    "employee": {
        "firstName": "Garcon",
        "lastName": "Mansur",
        "email": "mansur@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "541659898"
    },
    "address": {
        "location": "10424 rue du loili, Montreal, H9P1Z5"
    }
}
```

Most of the time, the employee entity inside the booking will be an employee that already exist in the database, but now each time I post this JSON, it created a new employee record in the db.

Comment: You need to find employee, and assign it findEmployee/findCustomer -> setEmployee/setCustomer and persist.  If not found, create employee or customer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to provide id field of an entity, hibernate will check and set automatically. If not, it will create new record.
But if it is not possible then check it manually as @YoManToMero mentioned